# qtcreator issue compiling with protobuff

Tags: protocol-buffers, qt-creator, ubuntu-16.04

Im trying to compile my code with a new version of protobuf (currently it was compiled with custom version, and i would like to compile it with the version that comes with the ubuntu via apt-get)

in the project settings i'v added `-lprotobuf`

```
.obj/Test.pb.o: In function `test_ns::protobuf_AssignDesc_Test_2eproto()':
<<path to file>>/Test.pb.cc:115: undefined reference to `google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::FindFileByName(std::string const&) const'
```

the line with the error('Test.pb.cc'):

```
void protobuf_AssignDesc_Test_2eproto() {
  protobuf_AddDesc_Test_2eproto();
  const ::google::protobuf::FileDescriptor* file =
    ::google::protobuf::DescriptorPool::generated_pool()->FindFileByName(
      "Test.proto");
```

i can see that the error caused when trying to  locate the file "Test.proto", but it exist in another directory, and it was used by the protoc command to generate Test.pb.cc and Test.pb.h files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fund the reason, the protobuff provided by the ubuntu compiled with different **ABI**, matching the ABI in our project fixed the issue